# Como puedo llevar mi api de actualizar datos en laravel hacia flutter por url

Tags: mysql, laravel, api, flutter, xampp

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Agradeciera su ayuda quizás para mucho es algo muy simple pero a mi me a costado muchos días y aun no lo logro, bien lo que quiero hacer es que he creado perfectamente en mi actualizar y funciona en postman  al llevarlo para flutter y pasarlo par editar mi grilla no me edita comprendo que tiene que ser algo que identifique mi columna con un id y al momento de darle editar me tome ese parámetro id de la columna y edite , gracias por la ayuda[image: y esta seria la interface donde quiero que haga efecto y se actualice es con un sfdatagrid]
[image: así es como es en postman]
[image: y así en flutter para hacer el llamado]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes pasarle el ID por la url para que entienda que producto estas editando.

```
var request = http.Request('PUT', Uri.parse('$apiURL/update/'+selectedEquipo));
```

Comment: Gracias funciona

Comment: Es un placer, puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta?